# Django port changing

Tags: django, python-2.7, ports

I've started Django server on localhost:8000 and everything wold be okay, but after clicking on different tabs it changes port to localhost:8002/othertab, how can I set 8000 for default port?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"clicking on different tabs"_ ? Do you mean tabs in the browser, or links in your django application?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid links in django, sorry I'm no so good at English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the server’s IP, pass it along with the port. So to listen on all public IPs (useful if you want to show off your work on other computers), use:

```
 $python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002
```

For more details [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) .

Comment: Don't work when I click on other link on site, it automatically changes adres to localhost:8002/link2

Comment: it works fine in my linux machine.

Comment: Thx, I didn't thought about that.