# Internet Information Services on typing localhost

Tags: iis, server, localhost

I use Windows 7

When I type localhost or 127.0.0.1 in my browser, there comes a page leading to the Internet Information Services.

I even disabled IIS from active Windows features, but it opens up the same page.

How can I change this to the default localhost directory?

Comment: Clean your browser's cache.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed IIS or Visual Studio, IIS landing page become home page for "localhost",

If you are trying to use localhost for php or any other server than IIS, you need to disable IIS or change IIS port.

**EDIT :**
If you are getting error even after disabling IIS,
consider changing port of Python Server (localhost),

you can do it by running this,

```
$python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8002
```

[this might have your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359389/django-port-changing)

[Django link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: am doing it for python

I tried doing it by appending the directory, but that's futile.
the error is    ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED...site can't be reached

Comment: have you checked if the port you are calling localhost on is free or not??
It might throw an error because of that.

Comment: You might change port of your localhost to 88.
I had same problem, changing port solved my problem.

Comment: I've change port for localhost in http.conf for php, don't know in which file you can change port number for python.

Comment: @sachsure, Updated the answer, if you find this helpful, accept this as an answer, and also upvote this, so that this can be helpful to others in future.